# How two compare the data between two table of database to report exact match and mismatched records in java

Tags: java, oracle11g, etl

I want to compare the data between two tables of database for a2a mapped columns and report separate matched and mismatched  records in excel. The web application   have screen to select specific table and provide mapping of columns. Based upon user input i am forming dynamic query and read data from database and storing in the `List<List<String>>` object for both source and target table.
My logic for finding the match and mismatch record is as follows,

`List<List<String>> sourceData= resultObj.getSourceData();`
`List<List<String>> targetData=resultObj.getTargetData();`

`List<List<String>> matchRecords=new ArrayList<List<String>>(sourceData);`
`matchRecords.retainAll(targetData);`

`List<List<String>> misMatchRecords=new ArrayList<List<String>>(sourceData);`
`misMatchRecords.removeAll(targetData);`

I want to improve my logic to get exact match and mismatch record because due to above approach reporting wrong mismatch in case of duplicate records...

Comment: You better do it in the database and not in the application leve.

Comment: I am handling this at application level as i wanted to generate excel report for source records, target records, match records and mismatch records. And for each validation operation there will be more than 5lakhs of records in both source and target so it will affect the database if i hit database 4 time to generate reports